# I can't boot into Ubuntu "Try (hd0,0): NTFS5: No ang0" Error Message

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, boot-failure

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 7. It was working fine but now when I try to boot with ubuntu after the operating system choice screen I get this.

[Boot Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISRKT.png)

> ```
> Try (hd0,0): NFTS5: No ang0
> Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: No ang0
> Try (hd0,2): NTFS5: No ang0
> Try (hd0,3): Extended:
> Try (hd0,4): NTFS5: No ang0
> Try (hd0,5): Extended:
> Try (hd0,5): EXT2:
> ```

And when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> it restarts the computer and if I chose to boot with ubuntu same thing happens again.

But windows works fine.. How do I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu via Wubi?
If you did, try going into Windows, and uninstall "Ubuntu", then reinstall it.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Boot into your windows and install EasyBCD.Then add a new boot entry for your linux.Then make sure that the NST folder which your linux is using to boot is in the system reserved memory for linux.